# What is an equation that fulfills these x and y values? (pretty easy I think)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, exponential-function

What is an equation (I'm assuming exponential) that fulfills (or at least approximates) the following:

```
If x is 100, y is = 1 million
If x is 10,  y is = 10
If x is 5,   y is < 1
If x is 0,   y is 0
```

I was originally thinking every 10 numbers will be another power of ten (which would be the expression $10^{x/10}$) but that would mean $100$ would be $10^{10}$ or $10$ million, not $1$ million. I'm stuck on how to get it to be just $1$ million...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site.  To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs.  For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$.

Comment: Oops. Let me fix it. Don't downvote anymore!

Comment: I haven't downvoted.  I'm trying to tell you how to avoid downvotes, like I said.

Comment: Okay I formatted it better, check it out :)

Comment: I’m sure there are many possibilities, but $x^5/10^4$ seems like a natural choice to me.

Comment: @Joe works for me!

Comment: To let you know my thought process for this problem: the fact that $y(0)=0$ suggested to me that a power function might make a better model than an exponential function, so I solved for $y=a x^p$ by using $(10^6/10)=(100/10)^p$ to get $p=5$, then solving $10=a 10^5$ to get $a=1/10^4$. Finally I checked that $y(5)<1$

Comment: @Joe thanks for that explanation on your thought process! That was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An exponential doesn't easily fit, because you want $0$ to be a possible value.

Probably the easiest thing is a polynomial: $cx^n$ for some suitable $c,n$. We need $c=10^{1-n}$ for the $x=10$ condition, so when $x=100$ we would get $cx^n=10^{n+1}$. This means we need $n=5$, so $y=\frac{x^5}{10000}$.

(This works by construction for $x=0,10,100$. It also works for $x=5$, where it gives $y=0.3125$.)